# Resolve IP address from hostname and print the result to Excel file

Tags: powershell

```
$servers = Get-Content "C:\Users\TEMP\Desktop\test.txt" 
$results = @()

foreach ($server in $servers) {
   [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server)
}

$result.servername = $server
$results += $result

$results | Export-Csv "C:\Users\adcops\Desktop\windows\serversandips.csv"
```

Comment: So, what is your question? Where does the variable `$result` come from?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Get-Content 'C:\Users\TEMP\Desktop\test.txt' | % {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Server = $_
        IP = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($_) -join '; '
    }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\Users\adcops\Desktop\windows\serversandips.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```